# Exact cost per ingredient in a recipe

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Math unfortunately hasn't been my forte.
I know this is fairly easy stuff but it needs to be precise. 
Please provide me with the answers. 
The steps would also be great.
Thanks

1. If **3175.15g** of salt cost **$5**, how much would **13g** of salt cost?
2. If **226g** of pepper cost **$4.20**, how much would **1.8g** cost?
3. If **25G** of spices cost **$20**, how much would **1g** cost?
4. If **994g** of special sugar cost **$17**, how much would **1.3g** cost?
5. If **750ML** of wine cost **$15**, how much would **35ml** cost?
6. If enough storage bags for **11339.8g** cost me **$22**, how much would it cost for enough bag for **453.592g**?

Comment: Assuming that you can buy each item in whatever quantity or partial quantity you desire, consider using ratios.  What would the ratio $\frac{3175.15~\text{g}}{5~\text{dollars}}$ represent?  How about $\frac{5~\text{dollars}}{3175.15~\text{g}}$?  If you multiply one or more of these ratios by $13~\text{g}$, does anything nice happen with cancellation of units?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than votes to close or downvotes if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Hints: if $3$ applies cost $5$ how much will $1$ apple cost? How about $2$ apples? Finally, the precision you're asking for is ridiculous in any practical sense. Why do you want these answers?

Comment: Ethan it isn't ridiculous, I'm making a food product and I want to know how much each one of my products cost me. I included what I pay per ingredient in grams. I also included the exact amount of each ingredient used in my product. I'm just trying to find out how much each ingredient costs me. I turned to the internet for help because I couldn't figure it out. I'm a chef and like I said before math isn't my forte..

Comment: No, it is quite ridiculous.  There is not a bag in existence that holds exactly 11339.8g of anything (nor is there any bag in existence that, if you have a sufficient integer quantity of them, holds that amount).  That degree of precision is laughable.  If you are actually in business and doing these computations, I would suggest that you hire an accountant or logistics manager.  Otherwise, find someone else to do your homework for you, please.

Answer (score 2):

All of those are solved using the same principle. I will do the first one as an example, here I will use $=$ as an equivalence rather than absolute equality.

$$3175.15g=\$5$$
Divide both sides by $3175.15$ to get
$$1g=\$\frac{5}{3175.15}$$
Now multiply both sides by $13$ to get
$$13g = \$\frac{(5)(13)}{3175.15}=\$0.020471473$$

Now use the same principle for the others

Comment: I'll upvote thsi for three reasons: it's correct, it's well written, and you've carefully said how you're reinterpreting the $=$ sign. But I wish you hadn't hurried to answer a badly written question when the OP showed no work.

Comment: I wouldn't have if I was not about to go to sleep. If he can understand this he can use to it convert anything to anything as long as he can get an equation to equate different quantities I think its no harm then